# Next.js with express.js can't Cannot find module 'next' when deployed to heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, next.js

When I deploy my next.js app to Heroku the build is successful but when I go to the URL i get the following error:

```
2021-10-28T12:09:12.195993+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-10-28T12:09:25.009085+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-10-28T12:09:26.339180+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-10-28T12:09:26.339201+00:00 app[web.1]: > @ start /app
2021-10-28T12:09:26.339202+00:00 app[web.1]: > NODE_ENV=production node server/server.js
2021-10-28T12:09:26.339202+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-10-28T12:09:26.520676+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
2021-10-28T12:09:26.520677+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-10-28T12:09:26.520678+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-10-28T12:09:26.520678+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-10-28T12:09:26.520679+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'next'
2021-10-28T12:09:26.520679+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2021-10-28T12:09:26.520679+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server/server.js
2021-10-28T12:09:26.520680+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
2021-10-28T12:09:26.520681+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
2021-10-28T12:09:26.520681+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
2021-10-28T12:09:26.520682+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
2021-10-28T12:09:26.520682+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/server.js:2:14)
2021-10-28T12:09:26.520683+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
2021-10-28T12:09:26.520683+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
2021-10-28T12:09:26.520683+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
2021-10-28T12:09:26.520683+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
2021-10-28T12:09:26.520684+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12) {
2021-10-28T12:09:26.520684+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-10-28T12:09:26.520685+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/server/server.js' ]
2021-10-28T12:09:26.520685+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-10-28T12:09:26.529543+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-10-28T12:09:26.529782+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-10-28T12:09:26.535573+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! @ start: `NODE_ENV=production node server/server.js`
2021-10-28T12:09:26.535667+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-10-28T12:09:26.535780+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-10-28T12:09:26.535863+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
2021-10-28T12:09:26.535941+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-10-28T12:09:26.543352+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-10-28T12:09:26.543474+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-10-28T12:09:26.543520+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-10-28T12_09_26_536Z-debug.log
2021-10-28T12:09:26.675484+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-10-28T12:09:26.879597+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-10-28T12:21:54.552275+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=clone-linktree.herokuapp.com request_id=35c017f9-99d6-45bf-bc36-876dceea183f fwd="212.60.107.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-10-28T12:21:54.797851+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=clone-linktree.herokuapp.com request_id=9a0fb742-93c7-4445-ab38-1cdf35cc9d8e fwd="212.60.107.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

It can't find the next module inside på server.js file which contain the following code:

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const passport = require('passport');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const path = require('path');
// OAuth Authencation setup
const passportSetup = require('./config/passport.js');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express()

    server.use(express.json());

    const cors = require('cors');
    server.use(
        cors({
            origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
            credentials: true
        })
    );

    // set up session cookies
    server.use(cookieSession({
        maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        keys: [process.env.cookieKey]
    }));

    // initialize passport
    server.use(passport.initialize());
    server.use(passport.session());

    // Routes
    const authRouter = require('./routes/auth')
    server.use('/api/auth', authRouter)

    const linkRouter = require('./routes/link')
    server.use('/api/link', linkRouter)

    // Mongoose setup
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    console.log('ATLAS_URI: ', process.env.ATLAS_URI);
    const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
    mongoose.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

    const connection = mongoose.connection;

    connection.once('open', () => {
        console.log('MongoDB database connetion established successfully');
    });
  
    server.all('*', (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res)
    })
  
    server.listen(port, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
    })
  })
```

And here is my package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server/server.js server/server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server/server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "^5.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "cookie-session": "^1.4.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
    "generate-password": "^1.6.1",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "heroku": "^7.52.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.3",
    "next": "latest",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.1",
    "nodemon": "2.0.6",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-color-palette": "^6.1.0",
    "react-colorful": "^5.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "swr": "^1.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
    "postcss": "^8.3.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.4"
  }
}
```

It builds and runs fine locally and does have any problems finding the modules. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried setting a specific Next.js version `"next": "^12.0.1"`?

Comment: Worked thanks :)